# Excel web query - timeout only after 10 loops

Tags: excel, vba, web

I'm trying to use an excel web query to extract data from multiple web pages.

The code runs fine for the first 10 loops, after which I get the error message:

> "Run time error 1004:Unable to open URL.The connection to this Internet site took longer than the allocated time"

I would appreciate any pointers.The website link is [here](http://www.skmm.gov.my/link_file/registers1/aa2.asp?cc=293468954920264181618&vl=&aa=celcom_cell&fpg=1)

The full code is below:

```
Sub DataPull()
Dim page As Integer
Dim Summary As Worksheet
Dim Query As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Set Summary = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
Set Query = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Query")

x = 2

For n = 1 To 11
With
Query.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://www.skmm.gov.my/link_file/registers1/_
aa2.aspcc=83885232640314699294053&vl=&aa=celcom_cell&fpg=" &n,_
Destination:=Query.Cells(1, 1))
.Name = "aa2.asp?cc=83885232640314699294053&vl=&aa=celcom_cell&fpg=1"
.FieldNames = True
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = True
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.BackgroundQuery = False
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = True
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
.WebDisableDateRecognition = False
.WebDisableRedirections = False
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With


Query.Range("A6:H35").Copy Destination:=Summary.Range("A" & x)
x = x + 30
Query.QueryTables(1).Delete

Next n
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem, but with a completely different web page.  I was importing the content of 12 pages, and on the 10th page, it would freeze up.  I found that placing a wait statement at the end of each iteration "fixed" the problem.

```
Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
```

I'd be interested to hear about what kind of timing works for you.  I know 5 seconds worked for me.  But I didn't try anything lower.  I got it to work, that was all I needed.

I would love it if Microsoft would place a configurable timeout value, or otherwise give us a way to wait on a background query a certain amount of time and then cancel it.  But alas, I have not found a way.  That said, this seems to be a problem with Excel not liking the programatic creation, refreshing, and deleting of 10 web queries in quick succession, as opposed to some issue with the underlying site being queried.